# What types of businesses are allowed to store SAD and in particular CVV data?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope

There must be some kind of business that requires the use of sensitive authentication data (SAD) data.  Could someone point me in the right direction on the requirement for the storage of that data?

Comment: Sure, like Google Pay, Apple Pay, etc.?

Comment: @schroeder I didn't think they were allowed to store CVV data.  Everything I've found says only card issuers are allowed to store CVV data, but I have been given the task of finding rare circumstances where other companies are allowed to as well.

Comment: Sign up for Google Pay and see for yourself ...

Comment: There's another factor that you might not be considering: that the CVV data is stored in such a way as to make it infeasible to connect to the PAN, but retrievable by the user.